# Deselect cell only if other cell in section is tapped

Tags: swift

I have a table view with two sections. Each cell in section 1 (the second section) has a tap accessory and a deselect method for when another cell in section 1 is tapped. However, if any cell in section 0 is tapped this also deselects the current selected cell.

My code is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .None
    }
}
```

I would only like the cells to be deselected if any other cell in section 1 is selected and ignore deselect for any other section.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For proper Reference, you need manage the reference in your globalArray itself, as shown below:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    .........
    if ( globalArray[indexpath.row][SELECTED_STATE] == SELECTED )
    {
     tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
    else 
    {
   tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .None
    } 
    .........


    }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //remove the pre selected state if needed by iterating the array

    globalArray[indexpath.row][SELECTED_STATE] = SELECTED 

    tableView .reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}
```